# How to find element by FindElementby ID or Xpath method using VBA Selenium

Tags: vba, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I wonder why VBA can't find element by id.
I want to input my ID and PW in homepage text box, but VBA can't find element.
(the error message is, "Runtime error: No SuchElementError")

My code is:

```
Dim Sel As New Selenium.WebDriver
Dim i As Object

Sel.Start "chrome"
Sel.Get "https://world.taobao.com/markets/all/login"
Sel.Wait 2000

Sel.FindElementById("fm-login-id").SendKeys "test my id"

Sel.Quit
Set Sel = Nothing
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The element you're looking for is within an iframe.
Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882564/1387701 which talks about using SwitchToFrame:

```
Sub HandleIframe()
    With New ChromeDriver
        .get "http://hcad.org/quick-search/"
        .SwitchToFrame .FindElementByTag("iframe", timeout:=10000)
        .FindElementById("acct").SendKeys "8227"
        .FindElementByCss("input[value='Search']").Click
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* to the **Username** field as the the desired element is within an `<iframe>` so youhave to:

- First `SwitchToFrame`.
- Then locate the element.
- You can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):
- Using `FindElementById`:

  ```
  Dim Sel As New Selenium.WebDriver

  Sel.Start "chrome"
  Sel.Get "https://world.taobao.com/markets/all/login"
  Sel.Wait 2000
  Sel.SwitchToFrame "login-iframe"
  Sel.Wait 2000
  Sel.FindElementById("fm-login-id").SendKeys "test my id"
  ```
- Using `FindElementByCss`:

  ```
  Dim Sel As New Selenium.WebDriver

  Sel.Start "chrome"
  Sel.Get "https://world.taobao.com/markets/all/login"
  Sel.Wait 2000
  Sel.SwitchToFrame "login-iframe"
  Sel.Wait 2000
  Sel.FindElementByCss("input#fm-login-id").SendKeys "test my id"
  ```
- Using `FindElementByXPath`:

  ```
  Dim Sel As New Selenium.WebDriver

  Sel.Start "chrome"
  Sel.Get "https://world.taobao.com/markets/all/login"
  Sel.Wait 2000            
  bot.SwitchToFrame "login-iframe"
  Sel.Wait 2000
  Sel.FindElementByXPath("//input[@id='fm-login-id']").SendKeys "test my id"
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to send text with in the username field within an iframe using Selenium VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59848281/how-to-send-text-with-in-the-username-field-within-an-iframe-using-selenium-vba/59848433#59848433)
- [Element doesn't exist although it has ID attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57075048/element-doesnt-exist-although-it-has-id-attribute/57075258#57075258)

---

### tl; dr

[Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)